# How to config my new ubuntu server to allow ssh connection from another network

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

I installed a new Ubuntu Server in my office, the system version is 16.04, and I have installed ssh. From whatismyipaddress.com website, I can see my real IP address, but I can't connect to the server through ssh. How to config the server, so that I can access it from my home or any other network?

Comment: Can you SSH to this server from within the same (office) network using the IP address you found from the web?

Comment: no, I can just access the server through 192.168 internal ip from my office

Comment: Is your office connected to the internet through a router?  Does the router have a NAT table and/or internal firewall?  Have you asked the person who maintains the router to open a port from the internet to your server?

Comment: +1 this is something you will need to arrange with the network administrator(s) of your workplace

Comment: Thanks all! I will ask our network administrator to config for me